# Can you return a class (as a type) instead of an instance of a class in C++?

Tags: c++

In Python, you can return a class instead of its instance from a function, because a class is just an instance of a 'metaclass' called type.

Can you do the same in C++? Say I want a function to return a class, so that the calling code can then take the returned class and call a static method on it without ever creating an instance of it. Possible ?

Comment: Not really, you can do something similar with template metaprogramming, but that will look rather different.

Comment: @UnholySheep so how do I pass class around ?

Comment: In C++, a **class** is a *type*, not itself an **object**.

Comment: Calling a static member function does not require an instance. If you have a `Class` and a `static void foo()` member function, `Class::foo();` is valid.

Comment: This is only going to work if your calling code (the code that needs to call the static function) knows all possible types at compile time.  C++ does not have reflection.  You could have a method return a `std::type_info` and then have a big-old switch statement.

Comment: You cannot pass a class around. Depending on your usecase you could probably use either templates or inheritance to achieve what you want, but without more information how exactly that would look is impossible to tell.

Comment: Another solution might be function pointers, altough what you want to do is still unclear.

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What do you want to do with the passed-around class?

Comment: C++ is statically typed, so a exact equivalent of this functionality seems unlikely. There may be elegant alternatives, but there's no way to tell, since you don't give us the "bigger picture" here. (As mentioned: probably a XY problem)

Answer (score 5):

You can't return a type; but you can return an identity object for a type. Then you can process it similarly to the given type. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

// in C++20, this is available as std::type_identity<>
template<typename T>
struct ID {};

template<typename T>
struct ToType;

template<typename T>
struct ToType<ID<T>>
{ using type = T; };

template<typename T>
using totype_t = typename ToType<T>::type;

struct MyType
{
    static fn() { std::cout << "ok" << std::endl; }
};

auto GetMyType()
{
    return ID<MyType>();
}

int main()
{
    auto proc = [](auto x) {
        totype_t<decltype(x)>::fn();
    };

    proc(GetMyType());
}
```

Note that, a function's return type must still be a given type, so you can't return this way based on runtime parameters. (You can, of course, use compile-time arguments for that.)

However, in C++ you also have *type aliases*. That's basically a way to write 'function-like' (mathematically: mapping) type expressions to define your type calculation. E.g.,

```
template<size_t I>
using MyType = std::conditional_t<(I < 50), char, int>; // if (I < 50) then char else int
```

A useful trick here is to use `decltype(expression)` for `expression`'s evaluation type.

Comment: Plus one, in C++20 you can refer to `std::type_identity` instead of writing a new type.

Comment: @davidhigh Indeed, including in the answer